# sqlplus not foud in docker

Tags: linux, oracle, docker

i have the problem is that sqlplus is not found in my docker oracle database.
can you help me.
i have always sh: sqlplus: command not found
i try to do a docker database;
i m beginer in docker 
i have try :

```
ENV ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus
RUN echo 'export ORACLE_HOME=u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus' >> etc/bash.bashrc
RUN echo 'export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH' >> /etc/bash.bashrc

FROM registry-innersource.soprasteria.com/sib/docker/db-oracle-12.2.0.1

# Set Environment Variables
ENV SYS_USER SYS
ENV SYS_PASSW password
ENV JAVA_HOME /jdk1.8.0_201
ENV ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus

COPY DB_SIB_SET_OS_COMMON_VARIABLES.sh /u01/oracle/
COPY 2_create_tablespaces.sh /u01/oracle/
COPY 3_setup_SIB.sh /u01/oracle/
COPY apache-jmeter-5.0 /u01/jmeter/
COPY JmeterScenario /u01/jmeter/JmeterScenario
COPY jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz /u01/java/
COPY Environment /Environment
COPY _util /_util
USER root
RUN chmod a+xr /u01/java/
RUN chmod 777 /_util

RUN echo 'export ORACLE_HOME=u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/sqlplus' >> etc/bash.bashrc
RUN echo 'export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH' >> /etc/bash.bashrc

RUN u01/oracle/1_initialise_SIB.sh 2>&1 | tee /tmp/1_initialise_SIB.log
RUN u01/oracle/2_create_tablespaces.sh 2>&1 | tee /tmp/2_create_tablespaces.log
RUN u01/oracle/3_setup_SIB.sh 2>&1 | tee /tmp/3_setup_SIB.log
USER root
RUN chmod a+xr /u01/java/
RUN chmod 777 /_util
RUN tar xzf /u01/java/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz

#RUN u01/jmeter/bin/jmeter -n -t u01/jmeter/JmeterScenario/Load_CSBroadcasts_FR.jmx

the error is always :
sh: sqlplus: command not found
```

Comment: this is the oracle_home , not all the way to the sqlplus binary . ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the the Oracle installation in your `registry-innersource.soprasteria.com/sib/docker/db-oracle-12.2.0.1` image is complete and that the paths are correct, the Oracle environment variables would be i.e.:

```
ENV ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
ENV ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1
ENV PATH=$PATH:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin
ENV TNS_ADMIN=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin
```

A reviewed `Dockerfile` could be i.e.:

```
FROM registry-innersource.soprasteria.com/sib/docker/db-oracle-12.2.0.1

ENV ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
ENV ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1
ENV TNS_ADMIN=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin
ENV PATH=$PATH:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin

RUN echo 'export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle' >> /etc/bash.bashrc
RUN echo 'export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1' >> /etc/bash.bashrc
RUN echo 'export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin' >> /etc/bash.bashrc
RUN echo 'export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH' >> /etc/bash.bashrc

# Set Environment Variables
ENV SYS_USER SYS
ENV SYS_PASSW password
ENV JAVA_HOME /jdk1.8.0_201

COPY DB_SIB_SET_OS_COMMON_VARIABLES.sh /u01/oracle/
COPY 2_create_tablespaces.sh /u01/oracle/
COPY 3_setup_SIB.sh /u01/oracle/
COPY apache-jmeter-5.0 /u01/jmeter/
COPY JmeterScenario /u01/jmeter/JmeterScenario
COPY jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz /u01/java/
COPY Environment /Environment
COPY _util /_util
USER root
RUN chmod a+xr /u01/java/
RUN chmod 777 /_util

RUN /u01/oracle/1_initialise_SIB.sh 2>&1 | tee /tmp/1_initialise_SIB.log
RUN /u01/oracle/2_create_tablespaces.sh 2>&1 | tee /tmp/2_create_tablespaces.log
RUN /u01/oracle/3_setup_SIB.sh 2>&1 | tee /tmp/3_setup_SIB.log
USER root
RUN chmod a+xr /u01/java/
RUN chmod 777 /_util
RUN tar xzf /u01/java/jdk-8u201-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

**Note**: removed the duplicate `RUN`'s appending to `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Also, not being able to find the `sqlplus` command is a configuration error, requires knowledge of Oracle Database / operating system configuration and not `docker` for say (the error is not `docker` specific).

Comment: @taveced can you open a shell inside of the container and verify that the database installation is correct, that the paths are correct and that the sqlplus binary exists in the directory as it should?

Comment: the sqplus only works when I go into the right folder manually and I throw it. after it is found everywhere but otherwise it is not foud

Comment: @taveced what is the right folder that you go into (e.g. absolute path)? Are using bash inside the container? Is the bash.bashrc being correctly sourced? What is the environment when connecting to the container?

Comment: I use bash inside the container .

Comment: i connect with  docker exec -it 468465d048a4 /bin/bash

Comment: the line is correcly add in the bashrc. how do you npw  the bash.bashrc being correctly sourced

Comment: @taveced when connected, is the $PATH correct? e.g. does it include the path to the $ORACLE_HOME/bin? Are all the oracle related environment variables present in the users environment (you can check using the ‘env’ command)? If they are not then that would suggest that the bash.bashrc file is not sourced when connecting to the container.

Comment: i think that is the .he bash.bashrc file is not sourced when connecting to the container do you now how to sourced it ?

Comment: @taveced I updated the `Dockerfile` example to include absolute paths just in case that's the issue. Using an image `FROM ubuntu:18.04` setting environment variables in `/etc/bash.bashrc` doesn't seem to be an issue, e.g. the variables exist in the users environment when running `bash` inside the container. What is the absolute path to `sqlplus` when you're connected to the container? What is the `registry-innersource.soprasteria.com/sib/docker/db-oracle-12.2.0.1` image extending? e.g. is not a publicly available image, can't download a copy to test with.

Comment: it is te oracle databse on docker. i have only change the name and add on my gitlab

Comment: @taveced I use a custom build of the Oracle DB Docker Hub image (single instance standard edition - https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance), the database installation is in `/opt/oracle/product/12.2.0.1/dbhome_1`, you need to make sure the environment is correct, e.g. that the paths set for the Oracle environment variables are correct. If you can't answer "what is the absolute path to `sqlplus` when you're connected to the container?" then unfortunately I can't help anymore.